# HTTP Status 500 - org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml]

Tags: java, hibernate, rest, jersey

i run my hibernate getArray function in my main class and it run successfully but when i use the same method in my jersey rest api it gives me:

```
HTTP Status 500 - org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml]
```

i tried to put the method in my main class and run it and it run successfully then i tried to call it from the resource class and it didn't work!
any clues here guys? 
This is my directory

[My Directory image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mmyuo.png)

And this is how i initialize the `sessionFactory`

```
File file = new File("src/main/HibernateResources/Hibernate.cfg.xml");
    sessionFactory = configuration.configure(file).buildSessionFactory(factory);
```

**please remember the hibernate works perfectly at any other class, it's just not working the rest api resources**

Comment: its seems hibernate not finding the cfg.xml fiie.Add  this file into your classpath.

Comment: yaa it seems that your hibernate.cfg.xml is at wrong place ... So please share your project structure ........... Or tell Inside which folder your hibernate.cfg.xml is ?

Comment: i have uploaded my directory and added the way that i initialize my sessionFactory object.