# org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource [C:\Users\marvi\workspace1\LoginApp\hibernate.cfg.xml]

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, servlets, jakarta-ee

I am trying to make a maven login application using hibernate to persist the data onto a mysql database. I am deploying the application on a glassfish server. I am able to start the server and fill in data on the html form but once I submit the form, I get the following error logs:

```
2016-11-21T22:40:05.371-0500|Info: HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.2.4.Final}
2016-11-21T22:40:05.379-0500|Info: HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2016-11-21T22:40:05.385-0500|Info: HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2016-11-21T22:40:05.471-0500|Warning: StandardWrapperValve[RegisterServlet]:Servlet.service() for servlet RegisterServlet threw exception
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at model.RegisterService.isExistingUser(RegisterService.java:8)
at model.RegisterServlet.doPost(RegisterServlet.java:59)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource [C:\Users\marvi\workspace1\LoginApp\hibernate.cfg.xml]
at org.hibernate.boot.cfgxml.internal.ConfigLoader.loadConfigXmlResource(ConfigLoader.java:53)
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.configure(StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.java:163)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:258)
at model.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:15)
... 32 more
```

I have moved the location of the hibernate.cfg.xml file from root folder, to the resource folder and also into the resource folder but problem prevails I have also added path of the cfg.xml file to the .configure() method, but did not work. I have looked at all the previously asked questions:
[ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml] in project root folder 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37879613/configurationexception-could-not-locate-cfg-xml-resource-hibernate-cfg-xml-in)

[Hibernate ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml] IntelliJ 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35675771/hibernate-configurationexception-could-not-locate-cfg-xml-resource-hibernate-c)

[org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource [/HibernateTest/src/hibernate.cfg.xml] 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35725306/org-hibernate-internal-util-config-configurationexception-could-not-locate-cfg)

[HTTP Status 500 - org.hibernate.internal.util.config.ConfigurationException: Could not locate cfg.xml resource [hibernate.cfg.xml]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40620803/http-status-500-org-hibernate-internal-util-config-configurationexception-cou)

but non of the solutions given fix my problem.

[image of Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkZfE.jpg)

Below is my code for my entity class.

```
package model;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;

import org.hibernate.annotations.NamedQueries;
import org.hibernate.annotations.NamedQuery;


@Entity
@NamedQueries({
  @NamedQuery(name="getUserByUserNameAndPassword",
              query="SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.userName = :uname AND u.password = :pword")
})
public class User{
@Id 
private Long userId;

private String firstName;
private String lastName;
private String userName;
private String password;

public User() {
}

//Getters and setters
}
```

Below is by hibernate util class.

```
package model;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
import org.hibernate.service.ServiceRegistry;

public class HibernateUtil {

private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory;
private static final ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry;

static {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.configure();
    serviceRegistry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().applySettings(conf.getProperties()).build();
    try {
        sessionFactory = conf.buildSessionFactory(serviceRegistry);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + e);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(e);
    }       
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
}
```

Below is my hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
<property   name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">password</property>
<property name="show_sql">true</property>
<mapping resource="User.hbm.xml"></mapping>
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

My servlet class

```
package model;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class RegisterServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/register")
public class RegisterServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
 */
public RegisterServlet() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
 *      response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
 *      response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    String fName = request.getParameter("firstName");
    String uName = request.getParameter("userName");
    String lName = request.getParameter("lastName");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");
    User user = new User();
    user.setFirstName(fName);
    user.setLastName(lName);
    user.setUserName(uName);
    user.setPassword(password);

    RegisterService rs = new RegisterService();

    if (!rs.isExistingUser(user.getUserName())) {//if user does NOT exist, then we register them
        rs.registerUser(user);//register the user first
            out.println("<h1>Registration Successful</h1>");
            out.println("To login with new UserId and Password<a href=login.jsp>Click here</a>");
            out.println("</center>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");
            out.close();            
    }else{//if user already exist
        out.println("<h1>Username Exists!!</h1>");
        out.println("To try again<a href=register.jsp>Click here</a>");
        //RequestDispatcher d = request.getRequestDispatcher("index.jsp");
        //d.forward(request, response);
    }




    //doGet(request, response);
}

}
```

My service class:

```
package model;

import org.hibernate.Session;

public class RegisterService {

public boolean isExistingUser(String uname) {
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.beginTransaction();
    User user = (User) session.getNamedQuery("getUser").setParameter("uname", uname).uniqueResult();
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();
    if (user.getUserName() != uname) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;

}

public void registerUser(User user) {
    if (!isExistingUser(user.getUserName())) {
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        session.saveOrUpdate(user);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();

    }

}

}
```

and finally my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>org.marv.servelet</groupId>
<artifactId>LoginApp</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>LoginApp Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.4.Final</version>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>LoginApp</finalName>
</build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your Hibernate.cfg.xml in src folder of your project and update the code as below and check if it works.
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
This will automatically fetch the .cfg file without mentioning it.